# Shake-to-undo working on CoreData app, but no undo/redo prompts shown

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

I have a CoreData based application which supports shake-to-undo.  This is currently working fine, however when I shake the device, the undo happens immediately, without first showing the usual undo prompt which NSUndoManager normally provides for free.

I've read "Using Undo on iPhone" from the "Undo Architecture" document and am:

- implementing `canBecomeFirstResponder`, returning `YES`
- making the view controller `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewDidAppear`
- making the view controller `resignFirstResponder` in `viewDidDisappear`
- redeclaring the `self.undoManager` in the view controller as read/write
- creating an `NSUndoManager` and setting `self.undoManager` in the `UIViewController` `init` method (which I've verified is getting called).
- setting `self.managedObjectModel.managedObjectContext.undoManager` to `self.undoManager` in the setter for `managedObjectModel`. Again, I've verified this is getting called. If I don't do this, undo doesn't work at all.

Troubleshooting I've already tried:

- checking undo does in fact work (I see changes to my managedObjectModel reverted)
- verifying `canBecomeFirstResponder` is being called
- checking if accessor `self.undoManager` is being called during an undo operation (which it is not).

So my questions are:

- under what circumstances does undo work but not show the undo prompts?
- What would you try next to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually tracked this down to some legacy code which was manually catching the shaking motion and calling undo on the undoManager; an implementation of motionEnded: in the view controller. Once this was removed, I started getting undo prompts again.